# Signature verification failed with Anchor - Solana

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I'm trying to sign a transaction manually with the anchor framework.

The following is the normal and currently working method to call the program:

```
await program.value.rpc.sendTweet(topic, content, {
    accounts: {
        author: wallet.value.publicKey,
        tweet: tweet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    },
    signers: [tweet],
});
```

Instead I want to be able to manually compile, sign and send the transaction, so I've wrote the following:

```
const transactionInstruction = program.value.instruction.sendTweet(topic, content, {
    accounts: {
        author: wallet.value.publicKey,
        tweet: tweet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    },
    signers: [tweet, wallet.value],
});

const recentBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

const manualTransaction = new Transaction({
    recentBlockhash: recentBlockhash.blockhash,
    feePayer: wallet.value.publicKey,
});
manualTransaction.add(transactionInstruction);

const transactionBuffer = manualTransaction.serializeMessage();

const signature = await program.value.provider.wallet.signTransaction(manualTransaction);

const config_serializer = {
    requireAllSignatures: true,
    verifySignatures: true,
};
const rawTransaction2 = manualTransaction.serialize(config_serializer);

await web3.sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(connection, rawTransaction2);
```

When i trigger the button, the wallet pop up, I confirm the transaction, but the I get the error: `Error: Signature verification failed at Transaction.serialize`

If I inspect the transaction after signing it, I cannot see any changes, so I'm definitely signing it wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

---

In the contract, Tweet is defined as follow:

```
#[account]
pub struct Tweet {
    pub author: Pubkey,
    pub timestamp: i64,
    pub topic: String,
    pub content: String,
}
```

The full code base is this one https://github.com/lorisleiva/solana-twitter

Answer (score 3):

Anchor's `Wallet` interface looks like this:

```
export interface Wallet {
  signTransaction<T extends Transaction | VersionedTransaction>(
    tx: T
  ): Promise<T>;
  /* ... */
}
```

That means that the `signTransaction()` method takes in a transaction and *returns* a promise for a signed transaction.

Your code assigns the return value, mistakenly, to `const signature` and then does not use it.

Instead, do this.

```
const signedManualTransaction =
  await program.value.provider.wallet.signTransaction(manualTransaction);
const rawTransaction2 = signedManualTransaction.serialize({
  requireAllSignatures: true,
  verifySignatures: true,
});
await web3.sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(connection, rawTransaction2);
```